# How to get items inside nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Vehicle",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": 1,
        "subCategoryName": "Car"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Delivery",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": 1,
        "subCategoryName": "Furniture"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Home Services",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": 1,
        "subCategoryName": "Lawn Mowing"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get all subcategories from all categories inside a single array called subcategories.

I have tried map, reduce, concat, etc. but cannot seem to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use destructuring to extract the `subCategories` array from each object and then use `.flatMap` to flatten it into an array like so:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:"Vehicle",subCategories:[{subCategoryId:1,subCategoryName:"Car"}]},{id:2,name:"Delivery",subCategories:[{subCategoryId:1,subCategoryName:"Furniture"}]},{id:3,name:"Home Services",subCategories:[{subCategoryId:1,subCategoryName:"Lawn Mowing"}]}];

const subcategories = arr.flatMap(({subCategories}) => subCategories);
console.log(subcategories);
```

If you want something a little more browser compatible, you can use `.reduce()` on your initial array by spreading the contents of each `subCategories` array into an accumulating array:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:"Vehicle",subCategories:[{subCategoryId:1,subCategoryName:"Car"}]},{id:2,name:"Delivery",subCategories:[{subCategoryId:1,subCategoryName:"Furniture"}]},{id:3,name:"Home Services",subCategories:[{subCategoryId:1,subCategoryName:"Lawn Mowing"}]}];
const subcategories = arr.reduce((res, {subCategories}) => [...res, ...subCategories], []);
console.log(subcategories);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to polyfill depending on your browser support needs, but this is what `flatMap` is great for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Let's say your example data is in a variable called `data`, call

```
data.flatMap(item => item.subcategories);
```